# openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar url is not working(https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz )

Tags: java, oracle, docker, devops, openjdk-11

In Docker file we are using the below url to download **jdk11** but its not working anymore.

**https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz**

**Getting error**

wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -O jdk.tar.gz -nv
The certificate's owner does not match hostname 'download.java.net'

**Is there any other way to download it?**

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What command did you use? Any error message being displayed?

Comment: @bratkartoffel I have updated please help me out.

Comment: The site presents certificate for "download.oracle.com", not for "download.java.net". Official installation guide (https://openjdk.java.net/install/) leads to Oracle's website, not to download.java.net. Probably your link is a bit deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site https://download.java.net/ has an SSL certificate error.

The configured certificate for this site lists the domain download.oracle.com (domain mismatch).

Maybe because The JDK 11 Early Access Program has concluded see:

https://jdk.java.net/11/

Try to download from:
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-upstream-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.3%2B7/OpenJDK11U-x64_linux_11.0.3_7.tar.gz

Comment: But in docker file what we have to add? If i add the url link it says forbidden error.

Comment: Please post the first line of the Docker file (the line with FROM)

Comment: using wget download it. RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -O jdk.tar.gz -nv && \
    mkdir -p /opt/jdk && \
    tar zxvf jdk.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk --strip-components=1 && \
    rm jdk.tar.gz && \
    rm /opt/jdk/lib/src.zip

Comment: I updated the link to an alternate location, I downloaded it and it works.

Comment: But how can i rely on this? I need to add it in production.

Comment: Use the link above to download the tar file.

Rename the file jdk.tar.gz.

Copy the tar file into the docker using the docker ADD command.

Comment: Then remove the wget command from the Dockerfile, this will ensure you have the Java tar file for your production builds.